# Request data from database after select in a form has been used

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am really sorry that I bother you again with my question, but this time I am asking about a kind of best practice. I found already various articles/posts about the topic and followed this article: https://makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax-in-laravel/ how to fill a second select based on the choice of a first select. As far as I can see, I have to use javascript and create new route.

My question would be is a new route the best idea because I also can also just call it by itself in the URL bar, eg. URL  /getEmployees/1

How can I archive that I still get the required information but at the same time avoid that the URL can be used. Do I have to fetch all required data in the controller itself before I return the view and then filter them?

Thanks

Stephan

---

### Update:

Another approach/try,

What is if I pass directly both tables to my view:

```
return view ('test')->with(compact('stuff_types'))->with(compact('positions'));
```

By the way, it really does not matter to select all data in the first instance, both tables will only have a couple of rows.
However, is it now possible to put a filter on the second table in the select view?

```
{{Form::select('position2', $positions, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"positions2"]) }}
```

I already tried $positions->where(‘id’, ‘1’), searched the internet for other ways but it always filles the select with the complete table information.
Later on I would love to put a filter with a javascript on the second table, based on the result of the first select, but at first it would be really nice just to see a where condition on it.

---

### Update 2

Ok, another update / question:

Instead of using laravel collectives with

```
{{Form::select('position2', $positions::pluck('name', 'id'), null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"positions2"])}}
```

I can use html and add an if condition, which I guess can be modified through javascript (will check tomorrow)

```
<select name="categories" id="categories" class="form-control">                                        
                                    @foreach($positions as $sector)
                                        @if ($sector->id == 2)
                                            <option value="{{ $sector->id }}">{{ $sector->name }}</option>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
```

But now I am struggling with my controller. Before I was using this:

```
$ positions = DB::table('positions')->pluck('name','id');
```

But this does not seem to work with a standard select so I had to change the pluck to get, but now the larabel collective is not working anymore

```
$positions = DB::table('positions')->get();
```

Can anyone explain we why get() works with html, but not with laravel collectives, and vice versa?

Comment: Is it important that one can't access the URL directly?

Comment: not really. I am just trying to learn laravel a bit and it just doesn't fell right. So I am reading something, trying to build something and come across questions ;)

Comment: If just typing the URL in your browser bar (GET method) generates changes server side, it's WRONG. If it just fetches data, and ideally is always the same for the same URL, it's alright.

Comment: Hi, I changed the question a little bit